# rails formtastic - integer field with enum as dropdown - '0' is not a valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have an integer field 'fieldname'.

enum drop: ['a', 'b']

```
f.input :fieldname, as: select, collection: Model.drops
```

After selecting and submitting, I am getting error '0' is not a valid fieldname.

Currently making it work by writing setters for integer fields using enum like this:

```
def fieldname=(value)
    self[:fieldname] = value.to_i
end
```

Can you tell me the proper way? I dont think writing this setter method is a good way.

Comment: What's your fieldname type in the database?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `.keys` to the collection definition:

```
f.input :fieldname, as: select, collection: Model.drops.keys
```

This way the option's value will be the same string as the text and on saving ActiveRecord will convert it to integer.